# Django identifying non field validation error is associated with which form

Tags: django

Is there a way to identifying the validation error is associated with which form for a template contaning multiple forms?

Let me explain the scenario. I have login window popup script within my base.html

```
<div id="dialog1" class="window">
    <form method="post" action="/accounts/login/?next=/IW/home" id='login-form' name=login-form>{% csrf_token %}

            <div class="d-header">


                {{ form.non_field_errors }} 
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="id_username" value="" onclick="this.value=''"/><br/>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" value="" onclick="this.value=''"/><br/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="login_form" value="1" />
                    <input type="submit" value="login" />   
            </div>          
                {% endif %} 
            </div>

    </form>
    </div>

<div id="mask"></div>
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
<script>
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();
//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
$('#mask').show();$('.window').show();

</script>
{% endif %}
```

As all other templates extends base,html whenever there is an error non_field error then login window pops up . I would like to show the login error only when login form is submit not on submit of someother form with a non field error.

For this I need to identify the name of the form.something like this  {% ifequal form.form_name login_form %} - Display login error .Is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

They isn't anything special about the name 'form' in the template. It's just a default context name, you can choose to name your forms anything you like.

Just name the forms differently in your context:

```
from django.http import Http404

def detail(request, poll_id):

    # NOTE: This view code isn't really form processing code, just using it to show
    #       how you can pass different names into your template context.

    login_form = MyLoginForm()
    detail_form = MyDetailForm()

    try:
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {'poll': p, 'login_form': login_form, 'detail_form': detail_form})
```

And then:

```
<div id="dialog1" class="window">         
   <form method="post" action="/accounts/login/?next=/IW/home" id='login-form' name=login-form>
       {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="d-header">
            {{ login_form.non_field_errors }}
    .
    .
    .
```

Also, if you want to do multiple instances of the same form type, have a look at [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/formsets/)